# Matlab issue regarding array size limit error

Tags: matlab, signals, regression

I have a signal Please have a look at the figure attached below.I want to average the values above 0.08 and below -0.08 on this signal in short applying regression technique on values above and below 0.08 and -0.08 respectively. I am using regstats command it is working best on simple signal but with my calculated signal I am having trouble. Please have a look at the attached picture below to have a look at that.

Can somebody guide me how can I avoid this issue.

My data set contains 1 * 2030678 and 1*2030678 on x and y axis respectively.

On x axis there is time and on y axis there is difference signal.

**I have also tried to change preferces of workspace to increase the size of array but its maximum upto 100000 in Matlab 2015a.**

Also have a look at linear analysis will it work fine with my signal.

Thanks in advance

```
   clear all
   clc
   drv(1)=load('20170420.mat');
   t=drv(1).q_T0;
   ref=drv(1).Pos;
   lws=drv(1).Angle;

    sig_diff=ref-lws;
    plot(sig_diff)
   up=0.01;

   low=-up;
   stats_up = regstats(sig_diff(sig_diff>up), t(sig_diff>up), 'linear'); 

   %calculate linear regression for upper values
   up_intercept=stats_up.beta(1);
   up_slope=stats_up.beta(2);
   stats_low = regstats(sig_diff(sig_diff<low), t(sig_diff<low), 'linear'); 
   %calculate linear regression for lower values
   low_intercept=stats_low.beta(1);
   low_slope=stats_low.beta(2);

   %plot subplot 2 in figure 2 with lin regression lines
   plot(t, sig_diff, t,t*up_slope+up_intercept,t,t*low_slope+low_intercept);      
   grid
   legend('diff','reg up','reg low')

   hysteresis = abs(up_intercept)+abs(low_intercept)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have more than 22 GB of RAM?

Comment: Thanks excaza for your reply yes I can manage but I have a lot of statistical data which require a large capacity for RAM so is there any way possible that i can divide my data into some matrices and proceed with that data but I have 6 more drives data similar to what i have mentioned in code above so I need in total 22Gb* 6 and that is too much so can u alos have  a trick to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to have been a bug in [MATLAB 2015 for adjusting the memory limit](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/249344-matlab-array-size-limit-error-why).

Your adjusting the maximum array size to "100000" is in reference to how large an array can be before it is saved to a .mat file when saved within a script.  It's not at all intuitive based on the names used in the preference panel, but you can check the reference for it here: [Threshold for saving variables to MATLAB script](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/set-workspace-and-variable-preferences.html).

Sadly, it seems you may need to get more RAM **or** update to a newer version of MATLAB.

**EDIT:**

A few other, general tricks are to

1. Decrease your precision from double to single.

   ```
   t=single(drv(1).q_T0);
   ref=single(drv(1).Pos);
   lws=single(drv(1).Angle);
   ```
2. Break your data into, possibly overlapping, sections and then stitch it back together.

The catch for part 1 is that `regstats` may create its own double arrays anyway, but it is a good way to reduce the limit from 22.0GB to ~11.0 GB if it works.  You are losing precision, but it may not be enough to worry about since you are regressing anyway.

The catch for part 2 is that you may need the entire signal for your regression to work correctly, or there may not be a good method for stitching the results back together (i.e. how can you do it and still make sense of the expected results).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply information but is there any other way to resolve this issue by storing data in some matrix or any other trick which will work because to get a RAM everytime with increase in statistical data is not possible.

Comment: The other way, that I know, is to get the next version of MATLAB :(.  Then you adjust the way it works and allow virtual memory to be used instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot information it also worked good and I also have found a solution I am sharing my answer for other people also. Thanks a lot for ur help and time.

Answer (score 0):

stats_up = regstats( sig_diff(( sig_diff>up)), t((sig_diff>up)), 'linear', {'beta'});

We can use beta to force regstats command to do specific calculations related to linear regression.

It works fine and save matrix array size.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for passing that along.